# For a composite foreign key, is a/why is a composite UNIQUE constraint in the referenced table required for a column combination with a primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have a question regarding explicitly defining of the uniqueness of something.  This relates to the creation of a composite foreign key.  I've created an example below to try and make my question as clear as possible (I've included some data inserts for ease of testing).

Each entry for `[Table1]` must have a unique `[Name]`.

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1]
(
    [ID]    INT IDENTITY            NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name]  NVARCHAR(255) UNIQUE    NOT NULL CHECK(LTRIM(RTRIM([Name])) <> '')
);

INSERT INTO [Table1]([Name])
VALUES
('Name 1'),
('Name 2'),
('Name 3'),
('Name 4'),
('Name 5'),
('Name 6'),
('Name 7')
```

Each `[Value]` in `[Table2]` must be unique for each `[Table1ID]`.

```
CREATE TABLE [Table2]
(
    [ID]        INT IDENTITY    NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    [Table1ID]  INT             NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Table1]([ID]),
    [Value]     NVARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL    CHECK(LTRIM(RTRIM([Value])) <> ''),

    --UNIQUE([ID], [Table1ID]),
    UNIQUE([Table1ID], [Value])
);

INSERT INTO [Table2]([Table1ID], [Value])
VALUES
(1, 'Entry 1'),
(1, 'Entry 2'),
(1, 'Entry 3'),
(1, 'Entry 4'),
(3, 'Entry 5'),
(3, 'Entry 6'),
(3, 'Entry 7')
```

Each combination of `[Table1ID]` and `[Table2ID]` in `[Table3]` must have a matching combination in `[Table2]` (I'm assuming that the two `FOREIGN KEY`s for `[Table1ID]` and `[Table2ID]` would be superfluous if the composite `FOREIGN KEY` is in place?).

```
CREATE TABLE [Table3]
(
    [ID]        INT IDENTITY    NOT NULL,
    [Table1ID]  INT             NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Table1]([ID]),
    [Table2ID]  INT             NOT NULL    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Table2]([ID]),

    FOREIGN KEY ([Table2ID], [Table1ID]) REFERENCES [Table2](ID, [Table1ID])
);

INSERT INTO [Table3]([Table2ID], [Table1ID])
VALUES
(5, 3)
```

That composite `FOREIGN KEY` constraint in `[Table3]` is the problem.  If that commented-out `UNIQUE` constraint in `[Table2]` is uncommented, `[Table3]` can be created successfully.  If it is not, the creation of `[Table3]` will fail saying "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key".

I understand the need for uniqueness with regards to keys, however as the `[ID]` column for `[Table2]` is a `PRIMARY KEY` and will always be unique, why would the `[Table1ID]` column not being unique in `[Table2]` prevent any combination of `[ID]` and `[Table1ID]` in `[Table2]` from being unique?

Basically, the `UNIQUE([ID], [Table1ID])` part seems pretty superfluous to me, yet it seems that the uniqueness of `[Table1ID]` in `[Table2]` must be explicitly defined in order for SQL Server to allow the creation of the composite foreign key in `[Table3]`.

Is that actually the case?  That this constraint, however superfluous it may seem, is required in order to allow the above?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes as you have discovered uniqueness must be declared.   I would question any data design that needs to do what you are asking.

Comment: Hey again, I put together the above as an example to demonstrate things.  Are you able to expand upon your data design comment?

Comment: Let me get this straight.  Table2 already has a relationship with Table1.  In Table3  wants to create a relationship directly between 1 and 2 and at the same time honor the prexisting relationship 2 has with 1.   Are you able to expand on any rational business needs for that type of relationship?

Comment: @Paparazzi [`Table1`] is a list of keys, such as the name of a list, `[Table2]` is a list of selectable values for each key, ie the values in the list, and `[Table3]` is the selected values from such a list.  Different users can select different values (hence the third table storing their selections), but everyone gets to choose from the same list of values (`[Table2]`).  The [`Table1`] reference may initially appear redundant, but it actually serves to provide some data integrity.

Comment: If someone decided to alter a `[Table2]` record so that it referenced a different `[Table1]` record (ie move a selectable value to a different list), but a record in `[Table3]` was already referencing it because one or more users had already selected that list value under the original key, the change would be prevented.  Without that additional `[Table1]` reference, the value the user had originally selected would implicitly move to a different list.

Comment: Right - I am not even going there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116391/discussion-between-interminable-and-paparazzi).

Comment: Thanks but I am not going there.  Even contrived it does not make sense.  The direct answer to your question is uniqueness must be declared.   What is the big deal with just declaring it?

Comment: @Paparazzi Because any combination of `[ID]` and `[Table1ID]` would always be unique anyway, meaning that there seemed to be no need to declare a constraint enforcing the uniqueness of combinations of `[ID]` and `[Table1ID]`.  I've also put a message in chat explaining what the structure is used for, if you're interested.

Comment: OK no need.  What is the problem with just declaring it?  I have no interest in this data design.  But thanks

Comment: @Paparazzi It's as I said above, any combination of `[ID]` and `[Table1ID]` in `[Table2]` will always be unique.  Thus adding the constraint `UNIQUE([ID], [Table1ID])` to `[Table2]` appeared to be redundant.  However, @Roger Wolf's answer below has pointed out to me that the `UNIQUE` index can be treated as a key, hence why that line is apparently necessary.  It's not needed to enforce the uniqueness of combinations of `[ID]` and `[Table1ID]`, it's needed to allow such a combination to be referenceable elsewhere. ^^

Comment: It is not necessary that SQL require it, but SQL does. It's obviously as trivial for a DBMS to tell that a FK references a superset of a PK/UNQUE as it is to tell that a FK references a PK/UNIQUE. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's more to do with the theoretical side of relational databases, actually.

What foreign key references in its parent table is not an arbitrary set of columns, however unique they might be; it references a key - either primary or alternate. And this key must be clearly declared as such.

Comment: And the `UNIQUE` constraint in the referenced table counts as referenceable key for the purposes of a composite `FOREIGN KEY` constraint?

Comment: @Interminable, yes - it is an alternate key, academically speaking. You might be surprised, but in SQL Server even a unique index can pose as a referenced key (not sure about filtered indices, though).

Comment: @philipxy, I think databases employ the "better safe than sorry" strategy here. You see, when you reference a key, it can't be dropped any longer. If, however, only the subset of columns is declared as a key, the database engine will have to do too much work trying to figure out whether it should allow you to drop a particular key from the parent table or not. Besides, the level of ambiguity that will arise from such a rule bending will be disastrous, imo.

Comment: Would you say that the two `FOREIGN KEY` constraints in `[Table3]` to `[Table1]` and `[Table2]` are superfluous with the composite foreign key?  Or would it be worth keeping the `FOREIGN KEY` to `[Table1]` as otherwise there would be no 'direct' connection to it from `[Table3]`?  Or would that be meaningless?

Comment: @Interminable, in most OLTP systems you wouldn't need a "direct" `Table3` -> `Table1` reference in the first place. Your schema looks more like a staging database rather than operational. You can avoid denormalisation by removing the `Table3.Table1ID` column completely without breaking any integrity or uniqueness. And when you need its value, you can always take it from `Table2`.

Comment: There's an additional data-integrity reason why the `Table1ID` field also exists in `Table3`.  It's not the layout for a staging database.  I've outlined what it was in my replies to @Paparazzi, above, which should hopefully help to make things clear.  It is a slight amount of de-normalisation, but I feel that the trade-off for the increased data-integrity is more worthwhile.

Comment: @Interminable, I see. In this case, remove the composite FK from `Table3` - it does not give you anything. Not every business rule can and should be enforced through schema - very few can, actually. If you want to prevent `Table2` records from having their parent changed, don't give UPDATE permissions on that column. Any additional logic can be implemented in stored procedure which will handle modifications of your tables. Alternatively, you can add versioning for `Table2`, with users selecting records from `Table2History` instead of the table per se.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't give me anything?  It does exactly what I require: `[Table1]` is a list of the names of each list.  `[Table2]` is a list of selectable items for each list.  `[Table3]` is a list of selected items from each list.  The composite `FOREIGN KEY` constraint prevents an already-selected item (in `[Table3]`) from being implicitly moved if a selectable item (in `[Table2]`) is moved to a different list (in `[Table1]`).  If it's not selected in `[Table3]`, the item can be moved without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any superset of a unique column set is unique. DBMSs could be programmed to understand this. But SQL requires you to declare the combination unique in the referenced table anyway.

PS In the relational model a foreign key must reference a candidate key, which must both be declared. But in SQL, UNIQUE declares a superkey and FOREIGN KEY declares a foreign superkey. (When a superkey contains no smaller superkey it's a candidate key.) One could prefer for ergonomic redundancy that the target of a foreign superkey declaration have an explicit matching unique declaration. But there's no theoretical or implementation justification for that.